# Function for converting octal to hexadecimal in Java

Tags: java

Is there a function I can use to convert octal to hexadecimal in java?

Comment: @Mr.L The link is not working now :)

Comment: @randombee yes it seems like the dns does not exist anymore. removed my comment.

Answer (score 5):

There's no single method, but you can easily do it via two steps:

- parse your `String` containing the octal value to an `int` (or a `long`, depending on expected range)
- Format that `int`/`long` to a hexadecimal `String`.

Those two steps can be done using [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [`Integer.toString(int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) respectively. Be sure to use the two-argument versions and pass in 8 and 16 for octal and hexadecimal respectively.

Comment: I would have up-voted this answer if it included the simple one-line code solution that the other answer included.  This answer just dances around it.

Comment: @Erick that's actually the reason to upvote *this* answer: it requires the OP to think and try for himself.

Answer (score 3):

This all assumes that your number, before and after, will be stored in a String (since it makes no sense to talk about base for an int/Integer):

```
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(someOctalString, 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String octalNo="037";
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(octalNo,8)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "1234";
String hex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(input,8));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This method takes octal input and convert it to Decimal
 * 
 * @param octalInput
 * @return  converted decimal value of the octal input  
 */
public static int ConvertOctalToDec( String octalInput )
{
    int a;
    int counter = 0;
    double product = 0;
    for ( int index = octalInput.length() ; index > 0 ; index -- )
    {
        a = Character.getNumericValue( octalInput.charAt( index - 1 ) );
        product = product + ( a * Math.pow( 8 , counter ) );
        counter ++ ;
    }
    return ( int ) product;
}

/**
 * This methods takes octal number as input and then calls
 * ConvertOctalToDec to convert octal to decimal number then converts it
 * to Hex
 * 
 * @param octalInput
 * @return Converted Hex value of octal input 
 */
public static String convertOctalToHex( String octalInput )
{
    int decimal = ConvertOctalToDec( octalInput );
    String hex = "";
    while ( decimal != 0 )
    {
        int hexValue = decimal % 16;
        hex = convertHexToChar( hexValue ) + hex;
        decimal = decimal / 16;
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
String oth=new BigInteger("37777777401",8).toString(16); //this is -255 to hex
System.out.println("octal to hex "+ oth);
```